# linkedIn for java

Tags: java, social-networking, linkedin-api

We are working on some social media project. I am looking for some java wrapper for linkedIn which is recommended.

For facebook restFB and for twitter  twitter4j are awesome. Something like that for linkedIn as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really recommend having a look at [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/). SpringSource have excellent documentation for all their libraries and the API is easy to use.

Comment: +1 for Spring Social...why to use different things for facebook, twitter and linked? Spring social will do it all for you.

Comment: is it free ? how deep it is bound to spring framework (if it is?)

Comment: Yes, it is free. I'm not too sure if you need to use Core Spring, since we were using it already before we used Spring Social. From what I can see here (http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/overview.html) you do not need anything except the Spring Social libraries.

Comment: got a little doubt. Do i really need to use springframework mvc to use it? In other words, I have no knowledge of spring framework. Right now I am using twitter4j, restFb in my web app for these two networks. And to do that i have to include their jars thats it. So, is using spring social same that is just including spring core and related libraries or i really have to use spring framework?

Comment: I don't think you need to use Spring Core. You just need the Spring Social Core libraries, and yes, it is as simple as including the jars. There might be a little bit of setup, but I think it is very minor. Have a read over the documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I heard somewhere that twitter module is yet not ready. Any idea by when it will be?

Comment: Not sure at all. But as a note, we have used the Twitter module to successfully pull and push messages.

Comment: oh then i think my statement is wrong. message pull is all what is needed for us.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/), its quite easy to work with.

Comment: yes saw that. but seeing only a single person contributing it which makes it risky to use going forward. Looking other active projects in the same direction

Comment: You could always "give back to the community" and help out on the project, if you can see something that could be improved. That would solve both problems of learning how to use it, and ensuring the project has support for your project in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Scribe library is used by many folks, and is actively being developed:
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java